# CGAL - Surface_mesh_shortest_path - geodesic walk

Tags: c++, c++11

With CGAL one can get the shortest path via two points doing a geodesic walk using Surface_mesh_shortest_path. I have similar problem in that I would like to do a geodesic walk but instead of having an end point I have direction and distance. In looking through the package I did not see a geodesic walk algorithm and wanted to inquire if there was one before writing my own.

That is does CGAL have the ability to return a geodesic path given a starting point, a directional vector and a distance? This is contrast to giving CGAL (Surface_mesh_shortest_path) a starting and end point and getting a geodesic path.